# Calender Import error in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have imported `java.util`
Even after the import the Calendar class shows me the following error.

> D:\Work>javac MyCalen.java
>   **MyCalen.java:1: error: cannot find symbol import java.util.Calender;**

So this is my error, could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Is your class  name also `MyCalen`?

Comment: Check your spelling, it's `Calendar` with an `a`. You should consider using an IDE to avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: Two stars is part of code or decoraction from error message? Real API class is Calendar (e<>a)

Comment: @Codebender->Thank you for your reply but I have both the ways i.e Calendar with an "a" and with an "e" but it dint work.

Comment: @Jens -> My class name is MyCalen